# How to declare and initialize variables within If Else Statement Android?

Tags: java, android

How do i pass the variable fTdee into another activity? I seem to have a problem because fTdee is declared within the If-Else statement but I don't think I actually access this variable fTdee from outside the If-Else Statement.

```
    final float fAF;
    float fTdee;
    String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();

    if (strAF.matches("OptionA"))

    {
        fAF = 1.20f;
        fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    }
    else if (strAF.matches("OptionB"))
    {
        fAF = 1.375f;
        fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    }
    else if (strAF.matches("OptionC"))
    {
        fAF = 1.55f;
        fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    }
    else if (strAF.matches("OptionD"))
    {
        fAF = 1.725f;
        fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    }
    else if (strAF.matches("OptionE"))
    {
        fAF = 1.90f;
        fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    }

            Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  CaloriesPage.class);
            in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
            startActivity(in2);
```

Comment: set a global variable

Comment: Declare fTdee outside the if-else scope. Also i recommend to replace if else spagetti with switch case.

Comment: It is out of scope. Just declare it before the if statement and you are fine. And yes you are accessing it outside of scope when you put it in the extra.

Comment: I've declared fTdee outside the if-else scope. But i can't seem to pass this to another activity with the Intent PutExtra because they are asking me to declare the variables as final which doesn't make sense to me because fTdee varies with different if-else conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare `fTdee` outside your statements. **AND** don't make them `final` it means that you cannot modify them after the instanciation.

```
float fAF = 0.0f;
String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();

if (strAF.matches("OptionA")){
    fAF = 1.20f;
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionB")){
    fAF = 1.375f;
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionC")){
    fAF = 1.55f;
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionD")){
    fAF = 1.725f;
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionE")){
    fAF = 1.90f;
}

final float fTdee = bmr*fAF;

Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  CaloriesPage.class);
in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
startActivity(in2);
```

Protip: Use better var names

Comment: What should you do if i get a prompt that says fTdee is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final?

Comment: Where do you access it elsewhere ?

Comment: Actually you can still have your `fTdee` `final` if you need it. I will update my answer.

Comment: I'd like to think i'm a step closer now. However i get a similar problem again. This time i get variable 'fAF' might not have been initialized

Comment: Yep that's because if your `strAF` equals something that you don't handle in your if/else statement it could be null. You could set it `float fAF = -1.0f;` like this if you are sure that it will be initialized in your if/else.

Comment: What's the negative sign for may i ask?

Comment: See my updated answer, actually it doesn't matter what the value is, if you are sure that `fAF` will be assigned in your if/else statement

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help! You got me to see this in another picture!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
float fAF;
float fTdee;
String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();

if (strAF.matches("OptionA"))

{
    fAF = 1.20f;
    fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
```

Comment: and remove the `final` keywords

Answer (score 0):

try to initialize the variable above if else block like this.

```
 final float fAF;
String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();
 float fTdee = 0.0;
if (strAF.matches("OptionA"))

{
    fAF = 1.20f;
    fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
else if (strAF.matches("OptionB"))
{
    fAF = 1.375f;
     fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
else if (strAF.matches("OptionC"))
{
    fAF = 1.55f;
     fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
else if (strAF.matches("OptionD"))
{
    fAF = 1.725f;
     fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
else if (strAF.matches("OptionE"))
{
    fAF = 1.90f;
      fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}

        Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  CaloriesPage.class);
        in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
        startActivity(in2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing programming brother. If you see something redundant, you must automatically realize that it can be reduced. You have declared fTdee in every if scope which is a really poor approach when it comes to good programming. Instead, as mentioned in the comments, declare a activity-level scope variable (initialize it to a default value) and set it's value whenever you want to (that is inside the if-else statements).

```
final float fAF;
float fTdee;
String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();

if (strAF.matches("OptionA"))

{
    fAF = 1.20f;
    fTdee = bmr*fAF;
}
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

The variable fTdee is visible only inside the if statement. May be this link can be useful http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html

Answer (score 0):

Declare intent object as you are declaring fTdee and then put fTdee value in the if-else statement. 
    float fAF;
    float fTdee;
    String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();
    Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  CaloriesPage.class);

```
if (strAF.matches("OptionA")){
 fAF = 1.20f;
 fTdee = bmr*fAF;
 in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionB")){
 fAF = 1.375f;
 fTdee = bmr*fAF;
 in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionC")){
 fAF = 1.55f;
 fTdee = bmr*fAF;
 in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionD")){
 fAF = 1.725f;
 fTdee = bmr*fAF;
 in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionE")){
 fAF = 1.90f;
 fTdee = bmr*fAF;
 in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
}
startActivity(in2);
```

PostScript: if you see with above soultion you are writing 
    fTdee = bmr*fAF;
    in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
again and again in if-else block which is redendunt. so to avoid this you can declare fTdee outside if-else block and can do some thing like this

```
float fAF=1.0f;
float fTdee;
String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();
if (strAF.matches("OptionA")){
 fAF = 1.20f;  
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionB")){
 fAF = 1.375f;  
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionC")){
 fAF = 1.55f;   
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionD")){
 fAF = 1.725f;   
}else if (strAF.matches("OptionE")){
 fAF = 1.90f;   
}
Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),  CaloriesPage.class);
fTdee = bmr*fAF;
in2.putExtra("mTdee",fTdee);
startActivity(in2);
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code you can't gurantee that `fTdee` is initialized, when you use it. You can add else statement in the end of your `if-else` statements tree.

```
    final float fAF;
    String strAF = tvAF.getText().toString();
    float fTdee = 0.0;
    if (strAF.matches("OptionA")) {
        fAF = 1.20f;
        fTdee = bmr * fAF;
    } else if (strAF.matches("OptionB")) {
        fAF = 1.375f;
        fTdee = bmr * fAF;
    } else if (strAF.matches("OptionC")) {
        fAF = 1.55f;
        fTdee = bmr * fAF;
    } else if (strAF.matches("OptionD")) {
        fAF = 1.725f;
        fTdee = bmr * fAF;
    } else if (strAF.matches("OptionE")) {
        fAF = 1.90f;
        fTdee = bmr * fAF;
    } else {
        fTdee = 0f; //some default value
        //or throw IllegalStateException if it is not possible for execution of your code
        //throw new IllegalStateException(); 
    }


    Intent in2 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), CaloriesPage.class);
    in2.putExtra("mTdee", fTdee);
    startActivity(in2);
```